# MySQL: How to update column from table1 by criteria from column in table2

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have two tables, called: `product_to_category` and `product_description`

```
product_to_category (product_id, category_id)

product_description (product_id, description)
```

I want to update column `description` by `category_id` number.

Comment: are you sure you have two databases or two tables??

Comment: I'm sorry I have two tables

Comment: Do you want update of matching product_id or not

Comment: So you want to update your production_description.description to be the category_id in the other table? Very confusing

Comment: In first table the product_id is match to category_id, let's say  there are 50 products in category_id = 5, I want to update description column only to products whitch are matched to category_id = 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update product_description d
join product_to_category c on c.product_id = d.product_id
set d.description = 'your new description'
where c.category_id = 'your category id'
```

Comment: Thank you dnll, your answer do work exactly that I want!

Answer (score 1):

I think below query will help you

```
Update product_description  set description = b.category_id 
From product_description a Inner Join product_to_category  b
ON a. product_id = b. product_id
```